# Configure Jenkins Hockeyapp plugin via Groovy script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I'm trying to configure the Hockeyapp plugin for Jenkins to take an API token from an environment variable. So far, I've manage to get something that works for the *initial* load of Jenkins, setting the API token, but if I change the environment variable and reload Jenkins the new token isn't applied.

My understanding of whats happening is my script is creating a new descriptor for Hockeyapp, and saving it - which works on initial Jenkins load as one doesn't exist. On changing the token and rebooting, a descriptor does exist and I'm not changing it, which is why the problem happens from the second boot onwards.

```
import hockeyapp.*

def env = System.getenv()
def hockeyappConfig = new HockeyappRecorder.DescriptorImpl()

String apiToken = env['HOCKEYAPP_API_TOKEN'] ?: ''

if (apiToken?.trim()) {
    hockeyappConfig.setDefaultToken(apiToken)
    hockeyappConfig.save()
}
```

Is anyone able to explain how to get the existing configuration for Hockeyapp via Groovy, so it can be edited, ideally with the code (my Java is not good)?

I think the answer lies *somewhere* in `Jenkins.getInstance()` and then pulling out the Hockeyapp config, but I'm getting a bit out of my depth with unfamiliarity in both Java/Groovy, and programmatic configuration of Jenkins.

Relevant JavaDoc:

- https://javadoc.jenkins.io/
- https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/hockeyapp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below groovy script worked for me - after using `getExtensionList` to get the current config it's possible to change the token.

> File: $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/hockeyapp.groovy

```
/*
    Set the default API token for Hockeyapp in global configuration

    Environment Variables:
    - HOCKEYAPP_API_TOKEN: Hockeyapp API Token
*/ 
import hockeyapp.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def env = System.getenv()

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def hockeyappConfig = jenkins.getExtensionList(HockeyappRecorder.DescriptorImpl.class)[0]

String apiToken = env['HOCKEYAPP_API_TOKEN'] ?: ''

if (apiToken?.trim()) {
    hockeyappConfig.setDefaultToken(apiToken)
    hockeyappConfig.save()
}
```